# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $scope.GetNomePacienteIndicou is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Quando vou abrir uma modal (AngularJs) é realizado a chamada da função: $scope.GetNomePacienteIndicou
Ao fechar essa modal e quando vou abri-la novamente o console do navegador apresenta o seguinte erro:

> ```
> agendactrl.js:1787 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $scope.GetNomePacienteIndicou is not a function
>     at b.$scope.ShowModalConvertPaciente (agendactrl.js:1787)
>     at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15358), <anonymous>:4:256)
>     at e (angular.js:26994)
>     at b.$eval (angular.js:18161)
>     at b.$apply (angular.js:18261)
>     at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:26999)
>     at HTMLElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
>     at HTMLElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
> ```

A função está sendo executada da seguinte forma (linha 1787 do código):

```
 Dados_Paciente = await $scope.GetNomePacienteIndicou($scope.chave_indicacao);
```

Função declarada:

```
$scope.GetNomePacienteIndicou = async function(chave_indicacao){

    chave = {};
    chave.chave_indicacao = chave_indicacao;
    PacienteIndicou = {};
    //console.log('teste getnomepaciente: ', chave);
    return AgendaService.GetNomePacienteIndicou(chave)
        .then(function(data){

            $scope.GetNomePacienteIndicou = data.data.dados[0];
            this.PacienteIndicou = $scope.GetNomePacienteIndicou; 
            return this.PacienteIndicou;
        });

};
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: This question belongs to https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in english language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overwrite the `$scope.GetNomePacienteIndicou` function:

```
$scope.GetNomePacienteIndicou = async function(chave_indicacao){
    chave = {};
    chave.chave_indicacao = chave_indicacao;
    PacienteIndicou = {};
    //console.log('teste getnomepaciente: ', chave);
    return AgendaService.GetNomePacienteIndicou(chave)
        .then(function(data){
            ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶G̶e̶t̶N̶o̶m̶e̶P̶a̶c̶i̶e̶n̶t̶e̶I̶n̶d̶i̶c̶o̶u̶ ̶=̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶.̶d̶a̶d̶o̶s̶[̶0̶]̶;̶ 
            return data.data.dados[0];
            //this.PacienteIndicou = $scope.GetNomePacienteIndicou; 
            //return this.PacienteIndicou;
        });
};
```

Also be aware that ES6 promises returned by `async` are not integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.